# Can anyone tell me about exception in running Spring framework basic example?

Tags: java, spring, exception

> Jul 15, 2014 4:10:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
>   INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [E:\theBckps\theBckps\Saurabh D drive\Eclipse_workspace1\SpringHello\src\applicationContext.xml]
>   Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from file [E:\theBckps\theBckps\Saurabh D drive\Eclipse_workspace1\SpringHello\src\applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load schema mappings from location [META-INF/spring.schemas]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.(XmlBeanFactory.java:73)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.(XmlBeanFactory.java:61)
>     at CheckIt.main(CheckIt.java:15)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load schema mappings from location [META-INF/spring.schemas]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.getSchemaMappings(PluggableSchemaResolver.java:153)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.resolveEntity(PluggableSchemaResolver.java:110)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DelegatingEntityResolver.resolveEntity(DelegatingEntityResolver.java:85)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.ResourceEntityResolver.resolveEntity(ResourceEntityResolver.java:74)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:107)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1100)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.resolveDocument(XMLSchemaLoader.java:595)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2432)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1782)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:705)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3103)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
>     ... 5 more
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\theBckps\For Post M (The system cannot find the file specified)
>     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:127)
>     at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:135)
>     at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:72)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.(URLJarFile.java:72)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:48)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:80)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:104)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:132)
>     at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:110)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.getSchemaMappings(PluggableSchemaResolver.java:144)
>     ... 28 more

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific. What are you trying to do? When is this error happening? What does the code around it look like?

Comment: I have started learning Spring framework by creating a simple "Hello World" example using eclipse Juno. Example consists of a bean class "GreetingImpl.java", "applicationContext.xml". On executing, above exception appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a Spring context fails to load, always check the **bottom** of the stacktrace.

Your error is here: `FileNotFoundException`

Make sure that your ZIP archive is in the classpath.

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\theBckps\For Post M (The system cannot find the file specified)
>     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:127)
>     at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:135)
>     at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:72)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.(URLJarFile.java:72)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:48)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:80)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:104)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:132)
>     at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:110)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.getSchemaMappings(PluggableSchemaResolver.java:144)
>     ... 28 more

Comment: Thanks for the help! The location where I kept my jars is having issues while accessing. So I replaced the location of jars and it worked out!